# <a href=""> with #scrollid and a GET variable

Tags: php, html, get

I hope someone can help me with this problem.
I'm trying to give this href an GET id, but the url alreay has a #scrollid what means it will scroll to a the place on the page where the #scrollid is.
but whenever I try to add an GET id to the url the #scrollid doesn't work anymore.

```
<a href="<?php echo $site_url, 'contact#scrollid?title=', 
$data['page']['slug']?>"Deelnemen</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After number sign (#) not send to server and for browser. So first write get parameter, then add #. Browser thinks all characters after # is element id.

```
<a href="<?php echo $site_url.'contact?title='.$data['page']['slug'].'#scrollid' ?>" >
  Deelnemen
</a>
```